# How to add bibliography/references to TOC in bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I have been trying to render my thesis with the bibliography added to the TOC.
After reading bookdown documentation carefully I have come to the conclusion that I must do the following:

```
bookdown::render_book(input = "index.Rmd",output_format = "bookdown::pdf_book", toc_bib = TRUE)
```

However, "unused argument" error is thrown in the console when I try to use it.
Now, the documentation says that the third argument of `render_book` is the `dots` (i.e. `...`) argument and that it gets passed to `output_format`, so it *should* work.

I'm confused here, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Have you tried `list(toc_bib = TRUE)`?

Comment: Yep. It says:
`Error in dirname(output_file) : a character vector argument expected`

Comment: Well then, you can turn it into a character vector with quotation marks, like this: `bookdown::render_book(input = "index.Rmd",output_format = "bookdown::pdf_book", "toc_bib = TRUE")`.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that won't work.

`Error: Failed to compile toc_bib = TRUE.tex. See toc_bib = TRUE.log for more info.`

It treats it like a new tex file.

Comment: Interesting, how about changing the second argument to `output_format = "bookdown::pdf_book(toc_bib = TRUE)"`?

Comment: Just to comment, I did manage to add the bibliography to TOC by adding `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}` to the markdown document.
However this feels like a "hack" and not a proper answer to my question (why is the high level function provided by the bookdown package not working) so I still leave this open.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::pdf_book", output_options=list(toc_bib = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add to the YAML in your thesis.Rmd file

```
header_includes:
- \usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```